# WIX how to remove xmlns="" tag

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix-extension

I have a wix project that installs a web site. One of the steps adds several xml tags to web.config file. Whenever adding xml tags WIX adds xmlns="" attribute which I don't want.

PluginSettings.wxi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  ...
    <?define PluginProbingPath="<probing privatePath="IntegrityChecker\bin\" />" ?>
</Include>
```

ConfigFiles.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <?include PluginSettings.wxi ?>
    <Fragment>
        <!-- WEB.CONFIG -->
        <Component Id="Web.ConfigPortal" Guid="3ED81B77-F153-4003-9006-4770D789D4B7" Directory ="INSTALLDIR">
            <CreateFolder/>

              ...
            <util:XmlConfig Id = "AppConfigAddPlugin1" ElementPath = "//configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding" Action = "create" Node = "document"
                On = "install" File = "[INSTALLDIR]web.config" Value  = "$(var.PluginProbingPath)" Sequence = "1"/>

        </Component>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Which results in web.config having this after install:

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         ...
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    <probing xmlns="" privatePath="IntegrityChecker\bin\"/></assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

As you can see nowhere did I specify xmlns tag (which I DON"T want).

I've tried removing that attribute with additional tag but it doesn't work:

```
    <util:XmlFile Id="AppConfigAddPlugin8" Action="deleteValue" Permanent="yes" File="[INSTALLDIR]web.config"
        ElementPath="//configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/probing" Name="xmlns" Sequence = "2"/>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WIX XmlConfig extension uses MSXML to modify the XML file on the target computer.  Specifically the attributes action="create" and node="document", results in this simplified sequence of MSXML calls:

1. `selectSingleNode("//configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding")`
2. Create new xml document from: `<probing privatePath=\"IntegrityChecker\bin\" />`
3. Get the top level document element
4. call `appendChild()` to append the new document element

The problem is the **probing** element has no name space, but the parent **assemblyBinding** element has the namespace `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"`.  When MSXML adds the **probing** element, `xmlns=""` is added to reset the default namespace.  Without `xmlns=""`, the **probing** element inherits the `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"` namespace.

The article, [MSXML inserted blank namespaces](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4de934a-b8a0-477b-9702-a3a050e39fa3/msxml-inserted-blank-namespaces?forum=xmlandnetfx%22), describes this behaviour. Unfortunately this article (and others) recommend changing the call sequence to specify a default namespace when adding the **probing** element. Since this is WIX we can't easily change how WIX uses MSXML.

You could try adding a namespace to the **probing** element:

```html
<?define PluginProbingPath="<probing xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" privatePath="IntegrityChecker\bin\" />" ?>
```

This will result in:

```html
<probing xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" privatePath="IntegrityChecker\bin\" />
```

I'm not an expert on xml namespaces, but the effect of the explicit `xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"` should be benign in that the **probing** element will now have the same default namespace as its parent **assemblyBinding**.  Whether this is a suitable work around depends on what is consuming the xml.